# be confused the use between adjective and adverb when it is in front of adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

How to use adjective and adverb correctly without being confusing. In this case because when I translate this sentence from my mother language to English, it fairly seem to be the same. Please help me. Thanks in advance

> 1. Cable cars are environmental friendly.
> 2. Cable cars are environmentally friendly.

Comment: @FF It's just possible.

Comment: @FF I thought that was a brilliant spot. I've just clocked who asked the question first time round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though 'friendly' ends with 'ly', it is not an adverb. Rather, it is an adjective, as in 'Cable cars are friendly.' When you want to describe an adjective, you use an adverb. For example, take the adjective 'red'. We want to say that an apple has a 'strong' red color. So we say, 'The apple is strongly red.' Note how 'strongly' is an adverb.

So in your case, the correct sentence would be 'Cable cars are environmentally friendly.' (But in Indian English, it is idiomatic usage to say 'Cable cars are environment-friendly'.)

Comment: I've never heard anyone say "environment-friendly" before.

Comment: @curiousdannii In India, we say 'environment-friendly' all the time.

Comment: That's interesting to hear, but that means it's probably a particular feature only of Indian English.

Comment: Perhaps it's a logical continuation of 'user-friendly', 'eco-friendly', etc.?

Comment: ... It's not incorrect to use 'environment-friendly', but it's not idiomatic in the UK or the US (as strongly suggested by [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=environment-friendly%2Cenvironmentally+friendly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenvironment%20-%20friendly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenvironmentally%20friendly%3B%2Cc0)) and answers favouring a partcular derivative form should indicate that. Arguing that 'logical' usages should always be considered acceptable is always very risky in English (eg "a book of John's ").

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edited. I do tend to make that risky argument often, though :)